# Users unable to create files/directories on NFSv3 mount, but can modify

Tags: linux, nfs, rhel6

I've got two RHEL 6 servers, one is an NFS server (we'll call it `nfs-server`, say its IP is `10.1.1.1`), and the other is a generic client for all intents and purposes (we'll call it `nfs-client`, say its IP is `10.0.0.1`).

Both `nfs-server` and `nfs-client` are connected to the same centralised authentication system, so UIDs/GIDs are the same for a given user.

`nfs-client` is mounting an NFSv3 share from `nfs-server:/shared_folder/cache` to `/shared_folder/cache`.

The `/shared_folder` directory on `nfs-server` is in mode `755`, owned by `root:root`, and the `/shared_folder/cache` directory is in mode `2775`, owned by `cache:cache` (UID=20014, GID=20004).

I have a set of users who are all members of the `cache` group in LDAP, but they cannot create or delete anything in the `/shared_folder/cache` directory itself on `nfs-client`. However:

- If a file already exists in `/shared_folder/cache` that has the correct permissions (writable by group `cache`), the users can modify the file, but not delete it (e.g. if `/shared_folder/cache/testfile` exists, and is writable by the `cache` group, the users can modify the contents of the file, but they cannot delete it)
- If a subdirectory already exists in `/shared_folder/cache` that has the correct permissions (mode `2775`, owned by `cache:cache`), the users can modify the directory as normal (e.g. if `/shared_folder/cache/testdir/` exists in mode `2775` and owned by the `cache` group, the users can add/modify/delete files and directories in `testdir`, but cannot delete `testdir` itself)
- If I log in as one of the users on `nfs-server`, all of a sudden I am able to create/modify/delete files and directories as normal within `/shared_folder/cache`

How can I fix this NFS mount? Diagnostic info is below the horizontal rule.

---

The output of `id user1` on both `nfs-server` and `nfs-client` shows:

```
uid=8173(<username>) gid=8173(<username>) groups=20004(cache)
```

`nfs-server` has the following export configured in `/etc/exports`:

```
"/shared_folder/cache"        <nfs-client-IP>(rw)
```

The output of `exportfs -v` on `nfs-server` shows:

```
/shared_folder/cache
                   <nfs-client-IP>(rw,wdelay,root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can the cache USER (uid 20014) create and delete files under /shared-folder/cache from the nfs client ?

Comment: Yes it can @PatrickTaylor

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a file requires write privileges on the directory.

You have correctly set `rw` in the mount options, but something seems to be wrong on the NFS side (since you can delete files by logging in the server).

Some things I would do:

- Check the default umask.
- Check permissions on the files using `lsattr`and `getfacl`.
- Ensure no one else is accessing that file while you're trying to delete it (`lsof`).
- If SELinux is in enforcing mode, check the audit logs (preferably using `audit2why`).
- Try adding the sync mount option.

As a last resort workaround, delete and create again users and groups on the server and restart the NFS server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Umask is fine (`0002` and `0022` for all pertinent users), no FACLs are set anywhere in the directory structure, lsattr doesn't reveal anything wrong, SELinux is disabled (not my choice, but at least we know that's not the source of the issue), and adding the sync mount option doesn't work. I can't delete and re-create the users since they are all LDAP users/groups, which are used by users across the environment.

Comment: @rst-2cv how about lsof? Is the file you're trying to delete being locked by something else?

Comment: My bad, I missed that one. (Un)fortunately not.